# Python: consolidar linhas duplicadas, somando valores

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho uma planilha em formato excel (.xlsx) com as seguintes colunas: "matricula", "nome", "valor", conforme imagem abaixo.

Eu gostaria de excluir os dados repetidos, somando os valores.

O resultado final deveria ser uma outra planilha em excel com apenas 6 (seis) linhas, igual a segunda imagem abaixo.

[image: Planilha inicial]

Abaixo seria a planilha com o resultado desejado.

[image: Resultado desejado]

```
import pandas as pd


planilha = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\wjrs1\Downloads\nova.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

arquivo = pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\Users\wjrs1\Downloads\teste.xlsx")

arquivo.to_excel(planilha, 'sheet1',index=False) #tem algo dando errado e não sei o que é

planilha.save()
```

Poderiam me ajudar? Agradeço antecipadamente.

Comment: planilha.groupby(['Matrícula', 'Nome', 'Valor'], as_index=False)['Valor'].sum()

Comment: Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). Exemplo: `planilha.drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `groupby` e depois o `to_excel` conforme abaixo

```
import pandas as pd

planilha = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\wjrs1\Downloads\nova.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

novo_df = planilha.groupby(['Matrícula', 'Nome'])['Valor'].sum().reset_index()

novo_df.to_excel("C:\Users\wjrs1\Downloads\teste.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet 1", index=False)
```